# Returning a list from an SNMP agent

Tags: perl, snmp

I'm using `NetSNMP::Agent` in Perl to query some values. Now I'm looking into how to return a list. EG table names, processes, etc.

Does one just create a new tree entry for each item when it gets queried or is there something that has to be predefined? I see similar lists when wandering through predefined MIBs. Just wondering what the mechanism is for ad-hoc values.

Also - is there a way to get such a list using `snmpget` or does this require `snmpwalk` every time?

Answer (score 1):

Here's some code I use to read a table (assume $session is an establish Net::SNMP session):

```
# I create a large hash of all the OIDs and their names
my %oidmap = (
    'vsvrServiceName' => '.1.3.6.1.4.1.5951.4.1.3.2.1.8',
    'vsvrServiceFullName' => '.1.3.6.1.4.1.5951.4.1.3.2.1.9',
    'vserverFullName' => '.1.3.6.1.4.1.5951.4.1.3.2.1.10',
    ...
);

# Choose which column names I want to extract from table
my @columnnames = qw(
    vserverFullName
    vsvrServiceName
    vsvrServiceFullName
);

# Get ALL entries in the table for those columns
my $vsvrEntries = $session->get_entries(
    -columns => [ map { $oidmap{$_} } @columnnames ],
    -maxrepetitions => 1,
);


# Decode the result column names, column values, and index
foreach my $key ( keys %{$vsvrEntries} ) {
    my $value = $vsvrEntries->{$key};

    # scan through OIDs to see if there's a match
    foreach my $oid_name ( @columnnames ) {
        my $oid = $oidmap{ $oid_name };
        next if ( $key !~ m{^\Q$oid\E\.(.+)$} );

        my $remainder = $1;

        print( "  $oid_name.$remainder = $value\n" );
        last;
    }
}
```

The hard part is getting the list of OIDs. To that end you can work them out yourself - or find a Linux server, stash your MIBs into `/usr/share/snmp/mibs` and use the net-snmp tools from the command line, e.g.:

```
user@myhost:~$ snmptranslate -I b -O n vsvrServiceName
.1.3.6.1.4.1.5951.4.1.3.2.1.8
```

Comment: Actually - I'm looking for how to *generate* and return a list. EG tables from a DB or files in a folder.

Comment: @ethrbunny oh my sincerest apologies I should have read your question more closely; you did say *agent*. Normally an SNMP agent returns one varbind (answer) for every OID listed in a single `get`, `getnext`, or `set` request. So the agent normally "handles" the list aspect - and calls back your handler once for each OID to handle...

Comment: So create a tree 'node' for each item returned? I've been trying to read (and understand) tables and containers without much luck. Maybe unrelated?

Comment: Oh this is less a Perl question - more a MIB and basic SNMP question? You'll have to write a MIB for your custom values. And/or carefully think about the OIDs and indicies. I'm not going to go into it here because the RFCs document this extensively.

Answer (score 0):

I'm have little experience using NetSNMP package, I use NET::SNMP, but if you can collaborate more on what exactly you are trying to achieve and post some sample code or specific OID references I might be able to help you...

Comment: How about returning a list of tables from a database?